# Kubectl follow logs until complete or timeout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

After I run a job, I'd like to follow its logs until it either completes or after a specified timeout in a bash script.

This can kind of be accomplished with the following:

```sh
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=30s job/data-job-name
kubectl logs job/data-job-name
```

The only problem with the above is that the timeout causes a failure, meaning the `kubectl logs` command never runs.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can just add ‘|| true’ at the end of the first command, it will continue to the next one even on failure

Comment: The default behavior of the shell would happily run the second command regardless of the exit code of the first command. In what environment are you running these commands such that a failure causes the shell to exit?

Comment: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Have you tried using without `timeout=30s`? Try to use [another flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) for example `kubectl logs --pod-running-timeout`
What distribution of OS are you using? Which version of Kubernetes are you using? Please provide your cluster configuration. Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.